# Adding column name to existing table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I want to add a column name for my table

```
create table flowers
(
     flowerName varchar (22) not null, primary key
)
```

Instead of the result being:

```
flowerName
----------
tulip
```

I want the result to be:

```
The Name of the flower is:
--------------------------
tulip
```

Comment: You do that in a query, not in the table.  `flowerName` is a really good name for the column.

Comment: thank you, but how?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like all you want to do is alias the column. This is easily handled by the following:

```
select flowerName AS [The Name of the flower is:] from flowers
```

Comment: thank you, but when I do a "select * from flowers",  the name changes back to flowerName in the result pane, I want it to always say "The name of the flower is"

Comment: @Hanna You can't alias *; each column must be aliased individually.

Comment: Since you want it to always be that way, you have two options that @zorkolot showed in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that on table creation, but you can do it on select in SQL, or change it in output in the language that you're using to connect.

If you want to do it in SQL, it would be something like:

`SELECT flowerName as 'The Name of the flower is' FROM flowers`

Answer (score 0):

This should be it.

```
create table flowers
(
     [The Name of the flower is:] varchar (22) not null primary key
)
```

If you want to alter the table name:

```
ALTER TABLE flowers
RENAME COLUMN "flowerName" TO "The Name of the flower is:"
```

Alternatively if you're adventurous (and don't want to change the original table structure) you can make a view:

```
CREATE VIEW vwFlowers AS
SELECT flowerName AS [The Name of the flower is:]
  FROM flowers
```

Then you can: `SELECT * FROM vwFlowers`

Comment: The view would be the right option in my opinion. Column names looking like that are a bootable offense.